# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'manager' was corrupted! and output screen does not stops even after using getchar();

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am working using visual c++ on windows 7. and getting the error error: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'manager' was corrupted. what could be the solution ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
    char  name[30];
    float age;
public:
    void getData(void);
    void putData(void);
};
void employee ::getData(void)
{
    cout<<"entr name";
    cin>> name;
    cout<<"entr age";
    cin>>age;
}
void employee ::putData(void)
{
    cout<<"name:"<< name<<endl;
    cout<<"age"<<age<<endl;
}
const int size=3;
int main()
{
    employee manager[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout <<endl<<"details of manager "<<i++<<endl;
        manager[i].getData();
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<< endl << "manager "<< i++ << endl;
        manager[i].putData();
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're on Windows 7 and you're still using char arrays instead of `std::string`? Why? That `cin >> name` is a buffer overflow waiting to happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
employee manager[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    cout <<endl<<"details of manager "<<i++<<endl;
    // PROBLEM IS HERE ----------->>   ^^^^^
    manager[i].getData();
}
```

When you increment i on the last iteration it becomes equal to the size and `manager[i]` is out of bounds. I think you meant not to increment i inside the loop, because you not only get out of bounds but also skip managers at odd positions. So here's what I suppose you intended:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    cout <<endl<<"details of manager "<<i<<endl;
    manager[i].getData();
}
```

Same refers to the other loop

Comment: @Mystical: What's 20 seconds? :)

Comment: @jeet.mg: Incrementing `i` in the `cout` statement doesn't make sense. It's already being incremented by the `for()` loop control.

Comment: i got it :) "const int size=3; " instead it must be =4

Comment: it is working a bit, loop must go thrice, but, its going twice

Comment: and what about holding the output screen ? i am seeing the output using break points.

Comment: Write `cin.ignore()` in the end

Comment: cin.ignore();
std::getchar();